# Create json structure with PHP and update datas

Tags: php, json

I'm using symfony2 and I need to create a json structure like that :

```
{
  "map": [
        [ X, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [ 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [ 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [ 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [ 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
  ]
}
```

I need to generation this array for then save to a file .json..

In this example, it's just an array 5-5, but I can have X-X, the size is in a variable `$size`.

So, how can I simply generate this kind of json with PHP ?

And an other problem, I need, after I have generated the json, update somes datas. Example, i need to replace the X by 8.

Comment: Simple. You build a PHP array and then `json_encode()` it. You NEVER build json directly. There's no point. It's easier to deal with your host platform's native structures, and then use json libraries to translate.

Comment: I misspoke, i know how to generate a json, but i don't know how to generate THIS json.. ^^

Comment: @ClémentAndraud One easy way to figure that out would be to write the JSON, then run `json_decode` on it!

Comment: Like I said. you DON'T generate the json yourself. Given that your example is already basically in json, you can (almost) json_decode() it back to a PHP structure and then `var_dump()` that. That'll show you exactly what you need to do in PHP.

Comment: @MarcB he doesn't want to generate the json himself. He doesn't know how to populate the PHP array. He knows to use `json_encode()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `json_encode()`

```
$arr = array(
  'map' => array(
    array(
        'X',1,1,1,1
    ),
    array(
        1,1,1,1,1
    ),
    array(
        1,1,1,1,1
    ),
    array(
        1,1,1,1,1
    ),
    array(
        1,1,1,1,1
    )
  )
);

echo json_encode($arr);
// outputs {"map":[["X",1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,1,1]]}
```

If you're ever unsure of what the PHP array would look to generate the JSON you're after, write a test sample of the json array you're after, and essentially run it in reverse! Use `json_decode()`, eg:

```
$json_string = '{"map":[["X",1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,1,1]]}';
print_r(json_decode($json_string, true));
```

Which'll then show you the array structure.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
 $Data = array(
            'map' => array( array('x','1','1','1','1'), 
                            array('1','1','1','1','1'),
                            ...
                            array('1','1','1','1','1')
                  )
        );

 echo json_encode($Data);
```